# Keras on Google Colaboratory: Incomplete iterations?

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, gpu, google-colaboratory

I'm running keras addition [rnn (seq2seq) example - here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/addition_rnn.py). I've tried running this on  1. Jupyter on  ubuntu VM, and also on Google colaboratory notebook with GPU.
But I'm afraid on Google Colab, it's not completing all the iterations. To be more specific,

Below are logs from regular jupyter notebook:

```python
Iteration 1
Train on 45000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/1
45000/45000 [==============================] - 75s 2ms/step - loss: 1.8899 - acc: 0.3209 - val_loss: 1.7819 - val_acc: 0.3429
```

Below are logs from Google colaboratory notebook.

```python
Iteration 1
Train on 45000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/1
17536/45000 [==========>...................] - ETA: 10s - loss: 2.0067 - acc: 0.2934
```

Note that after this incomplete iteration, it will not stop, instead it will move to next iteration. Below are Logs from next iteration on colab notebook -

```python
Iteration 2
Train on 45000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/1
34688/45000 [======================>.......] - ETA: 2s - loss: 1.7466 - acc: 0.3562
```

Note that I'm using the same code on both of these environments. I do not understand what is happening here. Why iterations are not completed on Google colab notebook? Is it something related to GPUs on Google colab? How do I fix this? Any pointers will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What evidence do you have of incomplete iterations? The logs you included do not show that.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is evidence, these numbers make me thinks so -- "17536/45000 ", "34688/45000". And in regular jupyter notebook it suggest time taken, like - "75s 2ms/step", and in colab notebooks, it suggests "eta" -- "ETA: 10s", "ETA: 2s"..

Comment: You would need to provide the full log in order to provide evidence, as the progress bar is implemented by writing partial results that you might interpret as "incomplete iterations". But if the progress bar does reach the end, then there is no way the epoch is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem in Co-Lab provides limited memory upto(12 GB) in cloud which creates many issues while solving a problem. That's why only 300 images are used to train and test.when images was preprocessed with dimension 600x600 and batch size was set to 128 it Keras model freezed during epoch 1 .Compiler did not show this error.Actually the error was runtime limited memory which was unable to handle by CoLab because it gave only 12GB limited memory for usage. Solution to above mentioned problem was solved by changing batch size to 4 and reduce image dimension to 300x300 because with 600x600 it still not work.
**Conclusively,Recommend Solution is Make Images dimension and Batch_size small until you get no error 
Run Again and Again by further changing batch size and image dimension small until there will no run time errorstrong text**

Comment: Thanks! My problem is not about images.. But anyway, will try you approach and let you know.

Comment: just make batchsize starts from 1

Comment: My training size earlier was 50000. I made it 20000, and it's working like charm. Thanks so much man!

Comment: @hafizahmadhassan my batch size is at 1 it still freezes at the start of the 3 epoch

Comment: reduce image dimension ...resize it to 64x64 or any parameter u can give small feature size to model

Answer (score 1):

One basic reason for such behavior of epochs is 'print' statement between two steps for a given epoch. However, incomplete progress bar due to this reason will not affect the model training.